# htaccess subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I was wondering if it's possible to create a subdomain using htaccess code only,
(Without setting one in the hosting control panel)

I have a folder named "mobile",
It's location is like so: http://www.domain.com/mobile

I want to be able to enter http://mobile.domain.com and see the mobile folder,
Is this possible to achieve only by writing some code in the htaccess?
if so, how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as long as it's configured to handle all requests for `*.domain.com` domains, then just make sure you have `mobile.domain.com`'s DNS CNAME'ed to `www.domain.com`.

If you know what subdomains you want, you can enumerate through them like so (putting these rules in the htaccess file in your document root):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mobile%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mobile%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [L]
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to do this arbitrarily, it gets a little more complicated:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1:%{REQUEST_URI} !^([^:]+):/\1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the config of your domains.

If you set them up with a wildcard `ServerAlias`, like so:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
```

The request will land in the folder and the `.htaccess` will be evaluated, enabling you to use mod_rewrite. If you don't specify the `ServerAlias` directive though, the request will never reach the folder and as such you wont be able to do anything with it.